# To Find conditions of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question is, given that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}a_k=a$, $n \in\mathbb{N}^+$, $k=0, 1, 2,\dots$, find the condition of $\alpha_{n,k}$.

Actually it’s easy to find a sufficient condition.
For instance, $\alpha_{n,k}\ge0$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\alpha_{n,k}=0$, and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}=1$. Proof follows:
$$\left|\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}a_k-a\right|=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}(a_k-a)\le\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}\lvert a_k-a\rvert$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a\implies\forall\varepsilon\gt0, \exists N_0\gt0,\text{ s.t. }\forall n>N_0, \lvert a_n-a\rvert\lt\varepsilon$$
and
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a\implies\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n-a)=0\implies\exists M_0\gt0,\text{ s.t. }\forall n, \lvert a_n-a\rvert\lt M_0$$
we get
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}\lvert a_k-a\rvert\lt\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}\alpha_{n,k}M_0+\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}\varepsilon$$
and
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\alpha_{n,k}=0\implies\exists N_1\gt0,\text{ s.t. }\forall n\gt N_1, \alpha_{n,k}\lt\varepsilon/[(N_0+1)M_0]$$
hence
$$\forall \varepsilon\gt0, \exists N=\max\{N_0, N_1\},\text{ s.t. }\forall n\gt N, \left|\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}a_k-a\right|\lt\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}\alpha_{n,k}M_0+\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}\varepsilon\lt2\varepsilon$$
then a sufficient condition is proved.

Then I tried to find out the equivalent condition, but I failed. I am eager to see solutions.

Comment: Can you give an example of such $a_n$ going to $a$, together with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{n,k}a_k$, also going to $a$?

Comment: @Dominique An example would be $\alpha_{n,k}=1/(n+1)$ for all $k$. Then $a_k\to a$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}a_k\to a$ by the [Cesaro mean theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean)

Comment: It seems like we are finding a generalised version for Cesaro mean theorem, except that $\alpha_{n,k}$ can be negative, which is the tricky part.

Answer (score 1):

I can only give some ideas for $\alpha_{n,k}\geq0$, in which case your conditions are almost equivalent.

> Let $(\alpha_{n,k})$ be a **non-negative** sequence, consider the $2$ statements:
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}a_k=a\ \text{for all real sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_k\to a$}, \tag{1}$$
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_{n,k}=0\ \text{for all $k$, and $\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}$ is bounded uniformly in $n$}. \tag{2}$$
> We have $(1)\Longleftrightarrow(2)$.

---

Proof of $\Longrightarrow$:

- If $\exists k^*$ such that $\alpha_{n,k^*}\not\to0$, then with $a_{k^*}=1$ and $0$ otherwise, it follows $\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}a_k=\alpha_{n,k^*}\not\to0$.
- If $\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}$ is not bounded, with $a_k\equiv1$ it follows $\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}a_k=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}$ is not bounded either.

Proof of $\Longleftarrow$:

Following your steps, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}a_k-a=\sum_{k=0}^N\alpha_{n,k}(a_k-a)+\sum_{k=N+1}^n\alpha_{n,k}(a_k-a)$$
for some $N\in\mathbb N$ independent of $n$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and since $\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}$ is bounded (say by $C$), we can fix $N$ such that $n\geq N$ gives $|a_k-a|<\varepsilon/(2C)$, then
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}a_k-a\right|\leq N\sup_k|\alpha_{n,k}|\sup_k|a_k-a|+\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon\ \ \text{for large enough $n$}.$$

---

If we remove the condition $\alpha_{n,k}\geq0$, then $\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{n,k}$ being uniformly bounded is no longer sufficient (but still necessary). However, $\sum_{k=0}^n|\alpha_{n,k}|$ being uniformly bounded is sufficient (but may or may not necessary). Hence, it could be something between abs. and cond. boundedness, and I really need to think about it.